# problem with image upload base64 vs formdata

Tags: angular

I have an image upload using Angular and backend is Java rest service
Should i be sending the image as base 64 or should I send it a formdata?
What are the deciding factors behind the decision?
is there a matter of performance?

Comment: Most of the time what I do is make separate `file upload` component which uploads through formdata and then return the string url of the uploaded image and then always send json data to backend making it nice and uniform. Since, json cannot be mixed with formdata in a single request. This is an approach i mostly use.

Comment: send as blob. base64 is larger than the file in some cases, unless you're cropping the file on the front end or compressing it before converting to base64 url. There are cases where it's okay such as profile pic where you crop only a part of the image to fit within a frame, but if you're displaying whole images, don't do this.

Comment: Base64 is a 33% enlargement of data size, but is of use in asynchrone AJAX calls to return JSON text to the server. An component can require AJAX. For the rest, especially with HTML 5 I think form data is still better in most cases.